# Listview items change order after scrolling

Tags: android, user-interface

I have scrollable Listview  with items. Every item has following layout.

I show or hide LinearLayout with id `customer_menu_index` as necessary. Ramaining elements are displayed in every method calling.

> ```
> <LinearLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:orientation="vertical" >
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/customer_menu_index"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="@color/menu_listview_item_alphabet_bg"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" 
>     android:visibility="gone">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/customer_menu_index_letter"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>         android:paddingTop="5dp"
>         android:text="bla"
>         android:textColor="@color/menu_listview_item_title"
>         android:textSize="10sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:typeface="sans" />
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/customer_menu_item"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="@drawable/menu_listview_item_selector"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/customer_menu_item_title"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>         android:paddingBottom="0dp"
>         android:paddingTop="5dp"
>         android:textColor="@color/menu_listview_item_title"
>         android:textSize="10sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:typeface="sans" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/customer_menu_item_subtitle"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/customer_menu_item_title"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>         android:paddingTop="1dp"
>         android:textColor="@color/menu_listview_item_subtitle"
>         android:textSize="8sp"
>         android:textStyle="normal"
>         android:typeface="sans" />
> </RelativeLayout>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

I use this layout in method `getView` of `BaseAdapter`. Implementation of getView method.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {

    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_menu_index_item, null);
    }

    LinearLayout indexLayout = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.customer_menu_index);

    HashMap<String, String> category = new HashMap<String, String>();
    category = mData.get(position);

    String currentIndexLetter = category.get(CustomerMenu.KEY_COMPANY).substring(0, 1);
    if (currentIndexLetter.equals(mLastIndexLetter) == false)
    {
        TextView letter = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.customer_menu_index_letter);
        letter.setText(currentIndexLetter);
        mLastIndexLetter = currentIndexLetter;
        indexLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.customer_menu_item_title);
    TextView subtitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.customer_menu_item_subtitle);
    title.setText(category.get(CustomerMenu.KEY_COMPANY));
    subtitle.setText(category.get(CustomerMenu.KEY_CONTACT_PERSON));

    return vi;
}
```

It works fine after loading. But when I scroll the listview, order of items is changed.

Comment: "// fill textviews with data" -- this portion is probably relevant.

Comment: I disagree with the first two comments. @m.brezovsky Could you post _more_ code, maybe your entire `getView()` method.

Comment: @Sam I've updated `getView()`. It is entire implementation of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a matching else statement to display *or hide* the LinearLayout:

```
if (currentIndexLetter.equals(mLastIndexLetter) == false)
{
    TextView letter = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.customer_menu_index_letter);
    letter.setText(currentIndexLetter);
    mLastIndexLetter = currentIndexLetter;
    indexLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    indexLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
}
```

Two other points:

- `if(a.equals(b) == false)` is the same as `if(!a.equals(b))`. This is simply a shortcut, you don't have to use this.
- You should also consider using a ViewHolder to speed up your code.

Comment: GONE is set in XML file `android:visibility="gone"`. This change don't resolve problem.

Comment: "GONE is set in XML" This will do nothing after you scroll the ListView. You should learn how ListView's RecycleBin works and how to use ViewHolders, this [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) explains these concept in great detail.  If the data is out of order, use your debugger to verify that `mData.get(position);` returns the data you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I've never hear about ListView's RecycleBin.